# Java - Object - Field and Method example - Basics

Tags: java

I am learning the very basics of Java and I decided to expand on an example a little further in order to understand it better.

In this instance, the object in question is a car. Let's say 'example car 1'.

The focus for my analogy is the engine temperature.

Firstly, I would view this as a field (state).
I also have a warning light for the engine temperature. Again, I would view this as a field.

Thinking about how they would interact I see it like this.

Engine temperature > 90°c ----> Warning Light -----> ON

To me, the method would be the switching on of the warning light.

Assuming I have been correct with the analogy so far, would there also be a method that would be the reference from the engine temp to the warning light?

so: If engine temp = > 90°c then refer to warning light <---- Is this a method of the engine temp?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would represent engine "temperature" as a field (as you said) and provide a `getEngineTemperature` and `setEngineTemperature` method. You can provide another method such as `hasEngineTemperatureWarning` to represent whether the temperature is in the dangerous range. Ultimately, however, these distinctions are up to you, the programmer, and there is no "always right" approach. But I think this is a good starting point.